# Kotlin: Casting via Class<T> with when-check, but it says "Type mismatch."

Tags: generics, kotlin

My intention is to use this class with different actions.
e.g: `HeadHelper<ActionOnlineStatus>(ActionOnlineStatus::class.java)`
in order to have only one function. But now a type mismatch error appears, and I'm curious about how to solve it because everything seems fine to me.

```
Type mismatch.
Required: T
Found: ActionOnlineStatus!
```

I already tried this `ActionOnlineStatus(connection.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) as T` but it's an `Unchecked cast: ActionOnlineStatus! to T` and I don't wanna use suppress annotations.

my code:

```
class HeadHelper<T : Action>(_action: Class<T>) : AsyncTask<Consumer<T>, Unit, Unit>() {

    private val action = _action

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Consumer<T>) {
        when (action) {
            ActionOnlineStatus::class.java -> {
                params[0].accept(action.cast(ActionOnlineStatus(true)))
                //Type mismatch.
                //Required: T
                //Found: ActionOnlineStatus!
            }
        }
    }

}

interface Action

class ActionOnlineStatus(_online: Boolean) : Action {
    val online = _online
}
```

Comment: If you're resolving `Class` at runtime there's no way to guarantee type safety at compile time, that's why `unchecked cast` warning appears. You'll have to suppress it or write custom `HeadHelper` class implementation for each available type of `T`.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply!

Comment: 1. `action.cast(...)` should return `T` because `action`'s type is `Class<T>`. So I can't see why the error should happen.

Comment: 2. There's no point to making `val action` separate from `_action`, instead it should be `class HeadHelper<T : Action>(private val action: Class<T>) ...`. Same with `online`/`_online`.

Comment: It also confuses me that `action#cast` returns `ActionOnlineStatus!` But thanks a lot for this hint, I always wondered if there's a possibility to put these vals in the constructor.